# The constant of the reverse Hölder inequality for polynomials

Tags: cv.complex-variables

Denote by $D(r)$ the disc at the origin of radius $r>1$. Denote by $P_m$ the set of polynomials of degree $m$. Since $P_m$ is finite dimensional, there is a constant $C(m,r)$ such that
$$
\|p\|_{L^{\infty}(D(r))}
\leq
C(m,r)
\|p\|_{L^1(-1,1)}
$$
for all $p \in P_m$.

I'd like some estimates for $C(m,r)$, especially the growth in $m$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I presume that $D(r)$ refers to a disk in the complex plane, in which case the maximum value of a polynomial (like any analytic function) is achieved on the boundary of $D(r)$. If $\|p\|_{L^\infty(D(r))} \le C \|p\|_{L^1(-1,1)}$, it means that the ball $\|p\|_{L^1(-1,1)} \le 1/C$ fits entirely into the ball $\|p\|_{L^\infty(D(r))}\le 1$ and by convexity it is enough to check that condition for the extreme points of the $L^1(-1,1)$-ball. So bounding $C$ from above is the same as bounding $\|p\|_{L^1(-1,1)}$ from below with $\|p\|_{L^\infty(D(r))} = 1$.

By a result of

> *Garkavi, A. L.*, The unit sphere of the space of polynomials with integral metric, [Mat. Zametki 1, 299-304 (1967)](http://mi.mathnet.ru/mzm9417). [ZBL0156.36603](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0156.36603), [MR209815](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/article?mr=209815).

the extreme points of the $L^1(-1,1)$-ball for polynomials of degree $m$ are those that have exactly $m$ roots in the interval $[-1,1]$ counting multiplicity. We can represent such a polynomial with $\|p\|_{L^\infty(D(r))} = 1$ as
$$
  p(x) = \frac{1}{N} (x-a_1) \cdots (x-a_m) ,
$$
where the normalization factor $N=(z-a_1)\cdots(z-a_m)$ for some complex $|z|=1$ and all the roots $a_i \in [-1,1]$, while
$$
 \|p\|_{L^1(-1,1)} = \frac{2}{N} \int_{-1}^1 \prod_{i=1}^m |x-a_i| \frac{dx}{2} \ge \frac{1}{C} .
$$
So to bound $1/C$ from below, it is enough to bound each factor from below.

For $N$, it is easy to see that $1/N \ge 1/(r+1)^m$, realized by $p(x) = (x+1)^n$ for instance.

For the integral, using the convexity of $\exp(x)$, we get
$$\begin{aligned}
  \int_{-1}^1 \prod_{i=1}^m |x-a_i| \frac{dx}{2}
  &\ge \exp\left(\int_{-1}^1 \sum_{i=1}^m \ln|x-a_i| \frac{dx}{2}\right) \\
  &= \exp\left(\frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^m \left[(1-a_i)\ln|(1-a_i)/e|+(1+a_i)\ln|(1+a_i)/e|\right]\right) \\
  &\ge \exp(-m) ,
\end{aligned}$$
where the last inequality is saturated when all $a_i=0$.

Putting together the pieces, we find that
$$
  C \le 2 e^m (r+1)^m .
$$
This <del>improves the bound from</del> is an alternative bound to [the other answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/450139). It gets rid of the the $(m+1)$ factor, but is is generally worse because the base exponent $e(r+1) > (2r+1)$.

Comment: Fantastic! Numerically,  this looks like it may be 4x too large.

Comment: @SébastienLoisel Interesting, I didn't think I'd get so close to optimal. If it's really needed, it should be possible to tweak the estimate by optimizing the product of $1/N$ and the $L^1$-norm jointly over the $a_i$, but that looks much more complicated. If it's relevant, the extreme points of polynomials under the $L^\infty(-1,1)$ metric are also known. They consist of those polynomials $p$ for which the number of roots of $1-p^2$ counted with multiplicity exceeds $m$ ([Konheim & Rivlin 1966](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/article?mr=191891)).

Comment: I agree one could tweak this by characterizing extremal polynomials, but all I did was numerically compute the best possible constant and divide it by the estimate, the graphs is [here](https://i.imgur.com/bbSrLyX.png), code is [here](https://pastebin.com/tLh8Pe4Q). The bound is actually quite pessimistic, but in the m=0 case, a factor of 4 seems to have happened. Looking at your argument in the case m=0, is it possible you multiplied by 2 instead of dividing by 2 at the end?

Comment: @SébastienLoisel Huh, can't see any obvious factors of 2 missing, but I may be too close to see it. The measure $dx/2$ is needed to give $[-1,1]$ unit weight, so that convexity could be used. Anyway, it was a fun problem! :-)

Comment: I think I meant to say, I think maybe you multiplied by 2 when you should have divided by 2 instead. It doesn't matter though, your argument remains the same. I had switched my accepted answer to yours but then I noticed the basis of your exponent is e(r+1), while my technique produces (2r+1), so in the end I might use my "linear algebra technique".

Answer (score 3):

Using Legendre polynomials as a basis, this is the bound I get:

$$
\|P\|_{L^\infty(D(0,r))}
 \leq {m+0.5 \over 2r}(2r+1)^{m+1} \|P\|_{L^1(-1,1)}.
$$

According to numerical experiments, this bound looks pessimistic by quite a bit. The $(m+1)$ term might not be necessary?

---

Now we justify the above statement. Let
$$
\langle u,v \rangle = \int_{-1}^1 u(x) v(x) \, dx.
$$
We denote the corresponding norm $\|\cdot\|_{L^2(-1,1)}$.
Let $\{T_k(x)\}$ be a family of orthogonal polynomials, e.g. Chebyshev polynomials. It is typical that these polynomials are not normalized in the inner product, but instead
$$
B(k) = \|T_k\|_{L^2(-1,1)}^2 > 0.
$$
Further denote
$$
E_p(k) = \|T_k\|_{L^{p}(-1,1)} \text{ and } F_p(k,r) = \|T_k\|_{L^{p}(D(r))}.
$$
The numbers $B(k)$ and $E_\infty(k)$ are available in closed form, and an upper bound for $F_\infty(k,r)$ can be obtained in a straightforward manner, although it takes a lot of calculation. Let $P(z)$ be an arbitrary polynomial of degree $m$, and write
$$
P(z) = \sum_{k=0}^m \alpha_k T_k(z)
$$
From the Hölder inequality and the orthogonality of $\{T_k\}$,
$$
B(k)|\alpha_k| = |\langle T_k,P \rangle| \leq E_{\infty}(k)\|P\|_{L^1(-1,1)}.
$$
This puts a lower bound, parametrized by $0 \leq k \leq m$, on $\|P\|_{L^1(-1,1)}$. Thus,
$$
\|P\|_{L^\infty(D(r))} \leq \sum_{k=0}^m |\alpha_k|F_{\infty}(k,r) \leq
\left(
\sum_{k=0}^m {E_\infty(k) F_\infty(k,r) \over B(k)}
\right)
\|P\|_{L^1(-1,1)}
$$
The expression in parentheses is $C(m,r)$.